# Why can't I use a diffrent user for SVN checkout

Tags: windows, svn

I trying to make SVN work on a Windows 2016 Server. I am using SVN over commandline. SVN is always using the user which is logged in. Let's say the logged in user is USER. The user needed for SVN is called SVNUSER. We are using a VisualSVN Server. Both Servers are inside a company network and they use the same AD for authentication.

I tried following stuff:

```
svn checkout --username SVNUSER http://svn01.de/svn/Application/trunk/FSW
```

or

```
svn checkout --username e102365 --password pass http://svn01.w3.de/svn/Application/trunk/FSW
```

didn't work. I get following error:

```
svn: E175013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://svn01.de/svn/Application/trunk/FSW'
svn: E175013: Access to '/svn/Application/trunk/FSW' forbidden
```

The serverlog says i tried to connect with USER.

The only way I was able to make the checkout work is using `run as` with the SVNUSER but I need it for automation and `run as` is interactive so it does not help.

The folder C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\auth is empty. When using tortoise SVN it says there is no saved authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your VisualSVN Server installation is configured for [Integrated Windows Authentication (Active Directory Single Sign-On)](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/windows-auth/) (see [KB182](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00180/#authentication-methods) for details).

Since it's Single Sign-On, you have to run your scripts as the user account that has permissions to access the repository. Specifying credentials in the command-line won't work - it will always authenticate as the user account who started the svn.exe client. You can try running your script from Windows Task Scheduler, custom Windows Service, etc.

Or you can enable Basic Windows authentication on the server in addition to Integrated Windows Authentication. And force your svn client to always prefer Basic auth (i.e., disable Integrated Windows Authentication on the client side). You can append the following option to your svn.exe commands:

```
--config-option servers:global:http-auth-types=basic
```

Or modify the `%APPDATA%\Subversion\servers` file. Add the `http-auth-types=basic` string under `[Global]`.